# Name for a path with least number of vertices.(Graph Geodesic)

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory

What is the name given to a path between to points that is of length equal to the distance from those two pints. Sorry to bother you but the definition was on a book I no longer have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you mean the [Graph Geodesic](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphGeodesic.html)

Comment: yes, that was it, thank you

Answer (score 0):

We generally just say "the shortest path".

Comment: Better to say "**a** shortest path."